# How can I determine which algorithm estimates GARCH(1,1) best?

Tags: estimation, optimization, model-selection, garch

In R, we have many packages to estimate the GARCH model. They choose different algorithms to estimate like quasi-Newton, SQP. Unfortunately, the estimated parameters are totally different from each other. Now, if I have real data, I don't know the real volatility. How can I determine which algorithm estimates GARCH(1,1) best? By objective function value? Ljung-Box test? Kurtosis, skewness? I have read some papers about that, but they mainly compare the result among different GARCH-type models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are estimating the parameters of a GARCH model with maximum likelihood, then you are after the set of parameter values that maximize the likelihood in the (training) sample. If several optimization routines yield different sets of parameter values, pick the one that maximizes the likelihood. The other ones have surely failed to reach the optimum in sample, while the one maximizing the likelihood at least *may* have reached it. (It could also be just another local optimum, too, but at least it beats the other ones under consideration.)

Comment: This answer applies not only to GARCH but also to any model that is estimated by maximum likelihood.

Comment: So, the MLE value is the only choice?

Comment: @Paul, based on the argument in my answer, I think so.